# Force Esper to use certain ScriptingEngine for parsing a dialect

Tags: java, esper

Hey Esper Professionals!

Is there a way/or workaround which allows me to force Esper to rely on a certain scripting engine (say Mozilla Rhino) for all expressions?

First of all, I am aware that we can configure the default dialect of Esper. For example, if we configure the default scripting engine to rhino like 
`config.getEngineDefaults().getScripts().setDefaultDialect("rhino");`

expressions like `concat(str) [  str + "sth"];` will be executed by Rhino.

Unfortunately, setting the default dialect is not enough if we want to force Esper to use a certain scripting language. The reason is that Esper allows the scripting dialect to be passed along with the definition:

```
js:concat(str) [  str + "sth"];
```

In this case, Esper will get the dialect name directly from the expression (here js) and bypass the default dialect (Rhino).

This is a huge problem if there are two scripting engines registered with the JVM for JS (js-> java 8 nashorn, rhino -> rhino), and we want to force the use of particular one.

The problematic behavior happens somewhere deep in

package com.espertech.esper.epl.script.jsr223

Forking the code is not an option for us.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a general Java question. The resolution of the scripting engine by Esper is in https://github.com/espertechinc/esper/blob/master/esper/src/main/java/com/espertech/esper/epl/script/jsr223/JSR223Helper.java

The class uses `new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName(dialect);`

If you want to force a different dialect than provided in the EPL you can either change that class or use the statement object model to override the dialect.